# Sed to add color to column for a specific pattern?

Tags: bash, sed

I figured out how to colorize column 3 in green like this:

```
green=$'\033[1;32m';off=$'\e[m';echo -e "num co1umn1 column2 column3\n=== === === ===\n1 this is me\n2 that is you"|column -t|sed "s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/$green&$off/3";unset green off
```

[CLI result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlNLq.png)

How do I need to alter my sed command to colorize the pattern 'is' only within column 3 so that the output becomes:

[Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSWoS.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to color the whole word `is`, you can use (with GNU sed):

```bash
sed "s/\bis\b/$green&$off/"
sed "s/\<is\>/$green&$off/"
```

Here, `\b` is a word boundary, `\<` is a leading word boundary and `\>` is a trailing word boundary.

[image]

Else, you can tell `sed` to start looking for matches from the third line:

```bash
sed "3,$ s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/$green&$off/3"
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That would colorize patterns other than 'is' as well.

Comment: @maria And what do you mean by that? If you needed to color `is`, why use `[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}` pattern? Just use `is`.

Comment: sed "s/is/$green&$off/3" doesn't colorize my 'is' pattern in column three.

Comment: @maria See my update.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to ignore the first two lines of the output in sed:

```bash
sed "1,2 ! s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/$green&$off/3";
```

Comment: That would colorize patterns other than 'is' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ ... | sed "/^[[:digit:]]/s/\(\([^ ]* \+\)\{2\}\)\([^ ]*\)/\1$green\3$off/"
```

Comment: That would colorize patterns other than 'is' as well.

Comment: @maria if you just want to color `is` then just use `sed "s/\<is\>/$green&$off/"`

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the `echo` to cover a couple other instances of `is` ...

```
$ echo -e "num co1umn1 column2 column3\n=== === === ===\n1 is is me\n2 that isn't you" | column -t
num  co1umn1  column2  column3
===  ===      ===      ===
1    is       is       me         # only colorize the 2nd occurrence of "is"
2    that     isn't    you        # don't colorize "isn't" in 3rd column
```

Extending OP's current `sed` solution:

```
sed -r "3,$ s/[^[:blank:]]{1,}/XXX&XXX/3; s/XXXisXXX/${green}is${off}/; s/XXX//g"
```

Where:

- `3,$` - apply following `sed` scripts against line numbers 3-to-EOF (ie, skip 1st 2 lines)
- first we offset the 3rd column values with `XXX` bookends (choose a set of characters that you know won't show up anywhere in the data)
- then colorize `XXXisXXX` (removing the `XXX`s at the same time)
- then remove any remaining `XXX` (from 3rd column in other rows)

This generates:

[image]